# Draw Document Numbering System Format (Updated)

Tags: tikz-pgf

In continuation to [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282262/draw-document-numbering-system-format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcX2K.jpg)

How can I draw the diagram without the (whatchamacallit) whiskers (see attached)?
Also how can I fix the overlap?

My code is:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\xdef\XPos{0}

\newcommand{\DNSF}[4]%
% lengths, separators, fillings, explainers
{   \foreach \L [count=\CountL] in {#1}
    {   \foreach \E [count=\CountE] in {#4}
        {   \ifthenelse{\CountL = \CountE}
            {   \ifthenelse{\equal{\E}{}}
                {}
                {   \node[text width=\L*3em, align=center, below] (dummy) at ({(\XPos+\L/2)*1em},-1) {\small\E};
                    \draw[-latex] (dummy.north) -- (dummy.north |- 0,0);
                }
            }{}
        }
        \foreach \D [count=\CountD] in {1,...,\L}
        {\draw (\XPos*1em,0.1) -- (\XPos*1em,0) -- ({(\XPos+1)*1em},0) -- ({(\XPos+1)*1em},0.1);
            \pgfmathparse{int(\XPos+1)}
            \xdef\XPos{\pgfmathresult}
            \foreach \F [count=\CountF] in {#3}
            {   \ifthenelse{\CountL = \CountF}
                {   \foreach \FF [count=\CountFF] in \F
                    {   \ifthenelse{\CountD = \CountFF}
                        {   \node[above] at (\XPos*1em-0.5em,0) {\FF};
                        }{}
                    }
                }{}
            }
        }
        %   \hspace{5.5mm}
        \foreach \S [count=\CountS] in {#2}
        {   \ifthenelse{\CountL = \CountS}
            {   \node at (\XPos*1em+0.5em,0.2) {\S};
                \pgfmathparse{int(\XPos+1)}
                \xdef\XPos{\pgfmathresult}
            }{}
        }
    }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \DNSF{6,4,8,1,3}%
    {,,,}%
    {{B,O,E,I,N,G},{B,7,3,8},{B,7,3,7,-,3,0,0},{M},{L,2,J}}%
    {Manufacturer,ICAO Designation,Aircraft,Medium,Landplane 2 Jet Engines}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whiskers? The overlap can be solved differenty. Either set the `text width` of the bottom nodes to be only as big as the the above part. Or increase the space between the elements (which can be done by putting them into matrices for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put each word (Boing, B738, …) into each own matrix you can use the matrix to place the whole construct which makes it easy to fix the overlap.

Technically, you could do everything into each own column of just *one* matrix but that needs to be approached very different.

I don't know quite what the rule for the `,,,` list is.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand*\DNSF[3]{
  \coordinate(start);
  \foreach[count=\groupI] \GROUP in {#2} {
    \matrix[matrix anchor=north west] at (start.north east) (start) {
      \tikzset{
        node distance=+0mm,
        start chain={ch\groupI} going base right}
      \foreach \LETTER in \GROUP
        \node[letter node, on chain=ch\groupI] {\LETTER};
      \draw (ch\groupI-begin.south west) 
         |- ([yshift=-2pt]ch\groupI-end.south east) coordinate (@)
         -- (ch\groupI-end.south east);
      \foreach[count=\labelI] \LABEL in {#3} {
        \ifthenelse{\groupI = \labelI}{
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nodenumber{(\tikzchaincount+1)/2}
          \ifthenelse{\isodd{\tikzchaincount}}{
            \coordinate (startarrow) at (ch\groupI-\nodenumber.south|-@);
          }{
            \coordinate (startarrow) at (ch\groupI-\nodenumber.south east|-@);
          }
          \draw[arrow style] (startarrow) -- ++(down:1) node[label node]{\LABEL};
        }{}
      }
     \\};
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  letter node/.style={
    text depth=+0pt,
    text height=+.7\ht\strutbox,
    text width=width("M"), align=center,
    inner sep=+.15em,
  },
  label node/.style={
    below,
    align=center,
    font=\small
  },
  arrow style/.style={
    Latex-,
    shorten <=1mm,
  },
]
\DNSF{,,,}
  {{B,O,E,I,N,G},{B,7,3,8},{B,7,3,7,-,3,0,0},{M},{L,2,J}}
  {Manufacturer,ICAO Designation,Aircraft,Medium,Landplane 2\\Jet Engines}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

Using the one matrix idea from above, we can do this with TikZ-CD and a few helpful settings.

Set `row sep` to vary the length of the vertical arrows.

I've minimized the inner and outer seps for the first row's nodes so that they are as close as possible together. However, `width("M")` still means that each letter reserves the space for the letter `M`, most likely the widest letter in the font.

If you don't need this, you can use the word itself and just one node.
This is what the second example with `word explainer*` does.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, chains}
\tikzcdset{
  word explainer/.style={
    math mode=false,  column sep=+.6666em, arrows=-Latex,
    /tikz/node letter/.style={
      text width=width("M"), inner sep=+.0em, outer sep=+0pt, align=center},
    /tikz/row 2/.append style={
      /utils/exec=\pgfpointdiff
        {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn'-begin}{center}}
        {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn'-end}{center}}%
        \pgftransformxshift{.5*\csname pgf@x\endcsname},
      execute at end node={\uar[shorten >=1mm]}, align=center, anchor=north},
    /utils/exec=%
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\nl\csname tikz@align@newline\endcsname
      \def\letters##1{%
        \draw[node distance=+0mm,
             /utils/exec=\edef\groupname{\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn'},
             start chain={\groupname} going base right] foreach \l in {##1}{
          node[node letter/.try, on chain=\groupname]{\l}}
           (\groupname-begin.south west) |- ([yshift=-2pt]\groupname-end.south east)
        coordinate[near end] (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
        -- (\groupname-end.south east);}},
  word explainer*/.style={
    math mode=false, column sep=+.6666em, arrows=-Latex,
    /utils/exec=%
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\nl\csname tikz@align@newline\endcsname,
    /tikz/row 1/.append style={ nodes={
       inner xsep=+.1em, inner ysep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,
        append after command={[insert path/.expanded={
            (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[to path={
              |- ([yshift=+-2pt]\noexpand\tikztotarget)
              -- (\noexpand\tikztotarget)}] (\tikzlastnode.south east)}]}}},
    /tikz/row 2/.append style={align=center, anchor=north},
    /tikz/row 2/.append code={\uar[shorten >=1mm+2pt]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[word explainer]
  \letters{B, O, E, I, N, G}       & \letters{B, 7, 3, 8}
& \letters{B, 7, 3, 7, -, 3, 0, 0} & \letters{M}
& \letters{L, 2, J} \\
  Manufacturer                     & ICAO Designation
& Aircraft                         & Medium
& Landplane 2\nl Jet Engined
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[word explainer*]
  BOEING       & B738 & B737-300 & M & L2J \\
  Manufacturer & ICAO Designation
& Aircraft     & Medium
& Landplane 2\nl Jet Engined
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're interested, a input syntax like `Manufacturer/BOEING, ICAO Designation/B738, …` is almost easier.

Comment: I like your answer. One more thing. How can I remove the space i.e. B O E I N G to be BOEING?

Comment: @OOzyPal The horizontal spacing is controlled by the `inner xsep`, the `text width` and the `node distance` – technically also the `outer xsep`. We only place each letter as a separate node so that each letter uses the same horizontal space. If you don't need that, it gets much more easier. (Or you just use a monospace font.)

Comment: @OOzyPal There is an easier approach by just placing the letters in one node while still having them equally spaced. This can make both approaches much easier.

Comment: I am sorry, but I kept fiddling with inner xsep and like with no avail.  Can you help me remove space between words i.e. B O E I N G to be BOEING?

Comment: @OOzyPal I've adjusted the TikZ-CD solution with minimal seps. But if you don't need the letters to use the same horizontal space, take a look at the example with `word explainer*`. It's just the word in a node itself with no special alignment.

Comment: Thank you. I worked great.